# Drawing a graph of potential energy as a function of displacement $x$.

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

The water density is changing linearly with the displacement x>0, i.e. $\rho = \rho_0 + kx$, where $\rho$ > 0 and k>0. Also, assume that $\rho_0V < m $.

I know that potential energy, $V = - \int F \ dx $.

I have that my Force, $F = mg - \rho Vg$. Where $m$ = mass, $g$ = gravity force and $\rho $ = water density.

$ 
\begin{align*}
    V &= - \int F \ dx  \\
     &= - \int (mg - \rho Vg) \ dx \\
&= - ( mgx - \rho Vgx + C) \\
&= -mgx + \rho Vgx + C_1
\end{align*}
$

When displacement is 0, the potential energy is 0, so this implies $C_1$ is 0. Therefore substituting in the value for $\rho = \rho_0 + kx$ we have that

$ 
\begin{align*}
    V &= \rho_0Vgx + Vgkx^2 -mgx
\end{align*}
$

I have to sketch this as a graph, where $V$ is a function of $x$. Don't know how to do this, because of all variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call $E$ the potential energy (don't use the same letter for Volume and energy...)
$$
E (x)= \rho_0Vgx + Vgkx^2 -mgx=\underbrace{Vgk}_ax^2+\underbrace{(\rho_0V-m)g}_bx=ax^2+bx=x(ax+b)
$$
is a parabola.

Comment: Alright that makes sense, thanks.